# « La cavalerie arrive, qui charge sabre au clair. »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

Une petite question me trotte dans la tête : ce type de phrase est-il correct ?

> La cavalerie arrive, qui charge sabre au clair.

On reprend le sujet de la proposition principale avec un pronom relatif, mais après le verbe. J'ai déjà vu cette construction plusieurs fois, même si je ne saurais dire où, et je ne sais pas si elle est fautive ou littéraire (ou bien simplement rare). Je n'ai rien réussi à trouver sur le sujet faute de mots-clefs appropriés. Quelqu'un pourrait-il m'éclairer de ses lumières ?

Comment: A mon humble avis, je ne vois pas de raison que ce soit incorrect.

Comment: Cette formulation est correcte pour moi également.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cette tournure est tout à fait correcte. Son style est littéraire.

Le [TLF (sens III.-C.-Rem. 2.e)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/qui) indique:

> En règle gén., *qui* peut être séparé de son antécédent par un compl., une prop., etc., lorsque l'intelligence du texte n'en souffre pas:

Deux exemples accompagnent cette remarque:

> *Son visage creusé, sa silhouette émaciée, ses prunelles souffrantes étaient là qui me bouleversaient* (Bourget, Disciple, 1889, p. 188)

et

> *Les fascistes ne voyaient son corps que jusqu'au ventre, et tiraient à qui mieux mieux sur ce buste incroyable en veston d'alpaga, en cravate rouge, qui lançait une charge de dynamite avec un geste de discobole, du coton dans les oreilles* (Malraux, Espoir, 1937, p. 540).

La construction donnée en exemple de la question répond tout à fait au principe ci-dessus. *Qui* est séparé de son antécédent *la cavalerie* sans que l'intelligence de la phrase n'en souffre. Et c'est précisément l'emploi de cette cette séparation qui donne à la phrase son style littéraire.

Answer (score 1):

On utilisera plutôt "La cavalerie qui arrive charge sabre au clair " dans un langage courant.

Comment: Bien que correcte, ta formulation n'est pas à utiliser préférentiellement, les deux sont tout à fait valables.

Comment: C'est celle qui sera utilisé dans la langage courrant quand même.

Comment: En même temps, placer *charger sabre au clair* dans un contexte du langage courant, c'est chaud. ^^